# WordPress - woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta doesn´t work

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook

I am trying to include a function after an order is updated (admin side), but it doesn´t work. I want to call a function when someone update an order (order status, etc...). I am trying this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'woocommerce_process_shop_order', 1, 1);
function woocommerce_process_shop_order () {
    // Code
}
```

Ive been trying to redirect to other web with `header("Location: www.example.com")`, but the page doesn´t redirect when an order is update :(

Please, can you help me to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Wrong hook. Since an order is a WP post, you can use the `post_updated` hook. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There you go. Tested and works. Goes into `functions.php` file of your child theme:

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'post_updated_action', 20, 3 );
function post_updated_action( int $post_id, WP_Post $post_after, WP_Post $post_before ): void {
    // To be sure it gets called when updated from the admin dashboard and is order
    if ( $post_before->post_type !== 'shop_order' || ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}
```